# Got error after execute function Srch.ContentBySearch.getPictureMarkup(... in display template

Tags: display-template

I am building my custom display template for the search results. I would like to use this code:

```
var title = $getItemValue(ctx,"Title");
var encodedId = $htmlEncode(ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId() + "_largePicture_");
var pictureId = encodedId + "picture";
var picture = $getItemValue(ctx,"Afbeelding");
picture.overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode);

var pictureMarkup = Srch.ContentBySearch.getPictureMarkup(picture, 468, 220, ctx.CurrentItem, "cbs-largePictureImg", title, pictureId);
```

This is the error:

Unable to get property 'getPictureMarkup' of undefined or null reference

I have copied this code from the OOTB display templates for webparts. What do I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The getPictureMarkup function comes from the **Content By Search** web part JavaScript file. So you need to load the **search.cbs.js** (/_layouts/15/search.cbs.js) on your page before you could start using that function.

You could try to load the file inside the display template with $includeScript.